# php docx file retrieval causing unreadable content

Tags: php, docx

I am trying to serve a docx file via php. It works but on opening I get an error saying unreadable content was in the file, do I trust it.

```
 $attachment_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."FILEPATH";
    if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {

        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
        header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.docx");
        readfile($attachment_location);
        die();        
    } else {
        die("Error: File not found.");
    }
```

I've tried a few suggestions but can't find a solution? can anyone see an obvious omission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add ob_clean(); in the begining of your if statement.

```
ob_clean();
```

Comment: Yes, sorry i tried to accept answer but was too soon